# How can I refresh a specific image after an update?

Tags: php, jquery

I have several div tags with unique ids and after a click event for a specific image I'm trying to refresh it.  How can I do this? This is what I have for code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="photo_gallery_container" <?php echo($div_id); ?>>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead >
            <tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                <th colspan="2" style="text-align: right;"><span style="cursor:pointer" id="delimg_<?php echo($id); ?>" class="delimg"><span class="label label-important">Delete</span></span></th>
            </tr>               
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="<?php echo($url['url'])?>" style="height:120px;"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" id="rotateimg_<?php echo($id); ?>" class="rotateimg">Rotate</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My click event for rotate looks like this:

```
$('.rotateimg').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(10);

    $.post("/functions/photo_functions.php", { f: 'rotate', imgid: id }, function(status){

        if (status == 'true') {

            // How can I reload the specific image after being rotated

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append a query string to the `img`'s URL (e.g. `?v=1`), which will fool the browser into thinking that it's a new image.

Here's an example (assuming `id` is the id of the image on the page):

```
$('#' + id).prop('src', function(i, v)
{
    var separator = v.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&';

    return v + separator + 'v=' + ( new Date() ).getTime();
});
```

---

Since it appears your `img` on the page has no ID, you could traverse the DOM to find it, like so:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('> img')
```

Comment: I just added the id to the img tag and this works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about a plugin?

```
$.fn.refresh(function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var source = $this.data('orig-src');
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

    if (!source) {
      $this.data('orig-src', $this.prop('src'));
      source = $this.data('orig-src');
    }

    if (source.indexOf('?') != -1) {
      $this.prop('src', source + '&t=' + timestamp)
    } else {
      $this.prop('src', source + '?t=' + timestamp)
    }
  });
});
```

Now you can call it on a `<img />` tag:

```
$('img.foo').refresh();
```